# Laravel authentication from different table is not working

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, i want to implement a login functinality for agents. I am trying to make the agents login from `'agents'` table. I have created controller and also added in `config/auth.php`, but its not working.

Following is my code in model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Agencie extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Sortable;

    protected $table = 'agencies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'agency_id';    

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'agency_id', 'agency_name','agency_user_name' ,'agency_password', 'agency_city', 'agency_state', 'agency_zip', 'agency_email','status','created_at','updated_at'
    ];

}
```

Following lines i have added to config/auth.php under `providers & guards`

```
'guards' => [
         'agency' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'agency',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'agency' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Agencie::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Following is the codes in routes.php

```
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'agency'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Agency\AgencyAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('agency_login');
        Route::get('/login', 'Agency\AgencyAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('/login', 'Agency\AgencyAuth\LoginController@login');
    });
```

Following is the code in controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Agency\AgencyAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hesto\MultiAuth\Traits\LogsoutGuard;
use JsValidator;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers, LogsoutGuard {
        LogsoutGuard::logout insteadof AuthenticatesUsers;
    }


    protected $validationRules = [
                                        'email' => 'required|email',
                                        'password' => 'required'
                                    ];

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // public $redirectTo = '/user/home';
    public $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard-graph';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin.guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#loginform');
        return view('agency.auth.login')->with('validator', $validator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('agency');
    }
    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        return ['email' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 'Active'];
    }
}
```

I have not added codes of view page, login form is loading succesfully, but if i provide "email id" and "password" from agency_table it is not logging in.

It is showing following error

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause
```

My table name is `admin_email`
Please help, what is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Are you, sure enough, you do have the email field in the table? Laravel by default uses email as username as the data for authentication.

As your table has "agency_email" column so you may have to change your Login controller as the doc says

**Username Customization**

By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'agency_email';
}
```

Comment: Yes, but agencies are my custom table,thats why i have added it as agency_Email and agency_apssword

Comment: Now am not returning any error, but it is not loggin in